# Change colors of Jasper

Tags: css, jasperserver

Please tell us how to change the color of dots on "li" tags in Jasper menu.
[image]

Content that is taken for dots is along the way: jasperserver/_themes/34815E2F/images/disclosure_indicators_icons_sprite@1x.png

I downloaded a defaulted image and replaced the color scheme and uploaded it to the theme/image folder.

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solving.
It is necessary to rename the custom image with icons, because the Jasper refers to the image from the default theme.